# power expressed as a ** b on Android

Tags: android, math, pow

I am converting an iOS app into Android.

On iOS, the app is using DDMathEvaluator to calculate the result of strings received from elsewhere.
Now on Android, I can't find DDMathEvaluator and have used ExpressionBuilder instead.

It works fine, except for parsing powers. On iOS, I can do `a ** b`, but on Android this wont work, I need to do it with `pow(a,b)`.

As I can't influence the strings I receive, I was wondering if there is anything available on Android that allows to evaluate `a ** b` ?

Comment: Could you point where did you get ExpressionBuilder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `a ^ b` instead of `a ** b`, [see Expression Builder's code for reference](https://code.google.com/p/adet/source/browse/trunk/adet/src/de/congrace/exp4j/ExpressionBuilder.java?r=12#102), it's one of the "builtin operators".

To transition between both, you can use [`String.replace`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29), which returns a copy of the input String.